# retrieved values position(order) changed every time in swift3

Tags: json, swift

I retrieved values from Json, i print retrieved values order changed(position changed) every time. please check my below code once:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  var myIds = [104016, 104010, 104014, 104018, 104000, 104038, 104015, 104011, 104015, 104010, 104010, 104010, 104003, 104003, 104011]

  for arr in 0 ..< myIds.count-1 {
    let url = URL(string: "http://.........\(myIds[arr])")
    print("myIds[\(arr)]:\(myIds[arr])")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
          print ("ERROR")
        }
        else
        {
          if let content = data
          {
            do
            {
               //Array
               let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
               var i = myJson["Job_title_name"]!
               var ist = ""
               // print("i=\(i)")
               ist = String(describing: i!)
               print("myIds[\(arr)]=\(ist)")

            }
            catch
            {

            }
          }
        }
      }
      task.resume()

    }

}

**output:**

 myIds[0]:104016
 myIds[1]:104010
 myIds[2]:104014
 myIds[3]:104018
 myIds[4]:104000
 myIds[5]:104038
 myIds[6]:104015
 myIds[7]:104011
 myIds[8]:104015
 myIds[9]:104010
 myIds[10]:104010
 myIds[11]:104010
 myIds[12]:104003
 myIds[13]:104003
 myIds[0]=WebLogic Admin
 myIds[3]=OracleDevloper
 myIds[2]=Node Js Developer
 myIds[1]=Angular Developer
 myIds[6]=HTML&CSS Developer
 myIds[5]=Senior Manager
 myIds[7]=CRM Developer
 myIds[4]=Windows Manager
 myIds[8]=HTML&CSS Developer
 myIds[9]=Angular Developer
 myIds[11]=Angular Developer
 myIds[10]=Angular Developer
 myIds[12]=java developer
 myIds[13]=java developer
```

This output is changed every time, when stop and run the app. but i'm unable to find the problem. please check my code once.

**Required output:**

```
myIds[0]:104016
myIds[1]:104010
myIds[2]:104014
myIds[3]:104018
myIds[4]:104000
myIds[5]:104038
myIds[6]:104015
myIds[7]:104011
myIds[8]:104015
myIds[9]:104010
myIds[10]:104010
myIds[11]:104010
myIds[12]:104003
myIds[13]:104003
myIds[0]=WebLogic Admin
myIds[1]=Angular Developer
myIds[2]=Node Js Developer
myIds[3]=OracleDevloper
myIds[4]=Windows Manager
myIds[5]=Senior Manager
myIds[6]=HTML&CSS Developer
myIds[7]=CRM Developer
myIds[8]=HTML&CSS Developer
myIds[9]=Angular Developer
myIds[10]=Angular Developer
myIds[11]=Angular Developer
myIds[12]=java developer
myIds[13]=java developer
```

i want the above output. In the above code whats my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Network requests run asynchronously, so this is the expected behaviour. The requests don't finish in the same order as they were started.

If you need your requests to run sequentially, you can run them using `DispatchGroups`, but this will lead to slower performance due to the fact that your asynchronous requests are executed sequentially instead of in parallel. A better solution is to store the results in a data structure, where you can identify the objects based on a unique identifier other than their index. For your current problem, the best solution is to store the results in a dictionary, where the key is the id and the value is the value from the network request.

Concurrent solution using a Dictionary to store the output values:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var myIds = [104016, 104010, 104014, 104018, 104000, 104038, 104015, 104011, 104015, 104010, 104010, 104010, 104003, 104003, 104011]

    var jobTitles = [Int:String]()
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for arr in 0 ..< myIds.count-1 {
        let url = URL(string: "http://.........\(myIds[arr])")
        print("myIds[\(arr)]:\(myIds[arr])")
        group.enter()
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil{
                    print ("ERROR")
                } else {
                    if let content = data{
                        do {
                            guard let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: []) as? [String:Any] else {return}
                            guard let jobTitle = myJson["Job_title_name"] as? String else {return}
                            jobTitles[myIds[arr]] = jobTitle
                            group.leave()
                        } catch {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
    print(jobTitles)
})
```

Some general advice: don't force unwrap values from a server response and don't use `String(describing:)` to create a String. Use optional binding or default values to safely unwrap the optionals and either cast your values to String if they are String values or just use `String(value)` for values from which Strings can be directly initialized (such as `Int`).

Comment: i tried Dispatch groups, gives error                                                                                                                                   let myGroup = DispatchGroup()
 myGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {
  let myJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: content, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as AnyObject
   var i = myJson["Job_title_name"]!
 var ist = ""
 ist = String(describing: i!)
 print("myIds[\(arr)]=\(ist)")
                        } as! @convention(block) () -> Void)

Comment: i tried the above code, it shows order changed every time

Comment: @swifttest check my updated answer, the dictionary approach is working fine, I just tested it.

Answer (score 1):

URLSession.shared.dataTask() usually call API in parallel execution so no matter if calling request order will same as response order.

If you want to call request and get response in same order then you should create NSOperation queue and make dependency on it.

Comment: i used DispatchGroup() also, still my problem not solved. I dont know how to use NSOperation.

Comment: Try this, it will help you to understand NSOperation - https://www.raywenderlich.com/76341/use-nsoperation-nsoperationqueue-swift